# How to fix Android Studio marking already commited files as changed [Git]

Tags: git, android-studio

Recently I noticed a problem with Android Studio's [v3.4] version control feature. I commited some files, and after a commit was done, few of those files remained highlighted with blue color, as if they weren't commited. They show up in Local Changes tab, when I open one of those files, I can see diff with previous version of that file. I tried to commit those files again, but I got an error:

```
Commit failed with error
0 files committed, 1 file failed to commit: *************
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
modified:   app/src/main/java/**********
```

In Log tab, when I select my last commit, those files are highlited with green color, as if they were new ones instead of just modified

How to make Android Studio not marking files as modified, if they were already commited?

Comment: Have you added/staged them before committing?

Comment: I use GUI in Android Studio, I don't do it in cli. In this GUI I just check/uncheck files/changes I wish to commit. So staging is transparent to me. As for adding - those files were added long time ago and were present in numerous commits before. But in last commit they appear like they've been added as new ones, instead of changed (marked with green text color instead of blue)

Comment: Are they missing in the commit before? Did you do some renaming on the way?

Comment: The thing is, even if I rename those files (which I didn't), they wouldn't be marked as changed right after commit.

Comment: I tried reseting commits to a state, when one of files in question was changed and commited earlier (saving whole project for each commit in between) and recreating each commit again - I returned where I started - same files, same problem. 
I deleted those files (after I copied them elsewhere) and ammended my last commit. After that I returned those files where they belong and ammended once more - voila, files ceased to be marked as modified. But in commit log there's notice next to each of them - 'renamed from' and exactly same name... And I'm sure, I didn't renamed none of them at all